# How can I require that browscap.ini / get_browser() is functioning before allow a my module to be installed?

Tags: 7, installation

I have a module for my Drupal 7.x installation which needs browscap.ini / get_browser().

The module works perfectly, but I want to make sure the browscap.ini is installed before installing of enabling the module. That way the module will not work unless browscap is installed correctly.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the name of the module that needs it?

Comment: Name of the module is: aserv_support. It's a self made module. I know it needs to be in the .install file, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Please post some code so we can debug better

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but why don't you just declare a dependency on whichever module (browsecap) you need?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using the following code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_requirements().
 *
 */
function aserv_support_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = [];

  if ($phase == 'install' || $phase == 'runtime') {

    if (!get_cfg_var('browscap')) {
      $requirements['aserv_support'] = [
        'title'    => t('Browscap not installed'),
        'value'    => 'Browscap has not be installed. Please install Browscap before enabling this module.',
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
      ];
    }
  }

  return $requirements;
}

/**
 *  Implementation of hook_enable()
 */
function aserv_support_enable() {
  if (!get_cfg_var('browscap')) {
    drupal_set_message(t('ERROR Enabling Aserv_Support: Browscap has not be installed. Please install Browscap before enabling this module.'), 'error');
    module_disable(['aserv_support']);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should keep in mind that there is a browscap drupal module, requiring a PHP module only when there is also a standard PHP version isn't a good idea. It would be better to require either one.